# Is there any way to stop Mutter from removing decorations/borders of maximized windows?

Tags: linux, gnome, window-manager, mutter

I would like to be able to resize maximized windows on Mutter.

Is there any way to tell Mutter to not remove the borders when the state is "maximized", so that I can maximize and then resize?

Or, if there was a way to "hijack" where Mutter performs this action and override the behavior--even forking Mutter.